# How can I justify the change of Sum and Integral sign??

Tags: complex-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:\Bbb{D} \rightarrow G\subset\Bbb{C}$ where $f$ is analytic and also $f$ is an isomorphism between $\Bbb{D}$ and $G$. $f$ has the series expansion $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n z^n$.

I must show that the area of $G=:S$ is

$$S = \pi \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n|c_n|^2$$

My try

I've already proved that $S = \iint_{\Bbb{D}} |f'(x+iy)|^2dxdy$. Now making the change $z=\rho e^{i\theta}$ the integral becomes

$$S=\int_0^1 \rho d\rho \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f'(\rho e^{i\theta})|^2 d\theta $$

Using the Parseval's Identity and with some little manipulations I get that the integral becomes

$$S =2\pi \int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 |c_n|^2 \rho^{2n-1} d\rho$$

Now if could just change the sum and integrate sign the result will follow inmediatly but I don't know right now how can I justify that $S$ can be written as

$$S = 2\pi \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 |c_n|^2 \int_0^1 \rho^{2n-1} d\rho$$

Any ideas??

Comment: Hint: Monotone convergence Theorem (Beppo Levi).

Comment: But I will have to verify that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2 |c_n|^2 \rho^{2n-1}$ is convergent. I don't see why @MarsPlastic

Comment: MCT applies regardless of whether the series converges or not. If it doesn't that means that the value of the integral is also $+\infty$.

Comment: Oh I see now. Thank you, your comment solves my question, if you want you can write it as an answer so I can accept it as an answer @MarsPlastic